# Automatically moving email from Deleted Items folder to another folder

Tags: outlook

My company uses a cloud Exchange system that deletes emails when they have been in the Deleted Items folder for 30 days (we use Outlook 2010 clients).  I want a script that would move all email from the Deleted Items folder to a second folder called "Trash".  I was able to find most of the following script online but it isn't working for me and I'm not sure what is missing/incorrect.  Any help is appreciated...

```
Sub MoveDeletedItems()
Dim oSource As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oTarget As OutlookMAPIFolder
Dim oDummy As Object
Dim oToMove As Object
Dim colItems As Outlook.Items
Dim i As Long

Set oSource = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
Set oTarget = oSource.Folders.Folder("Trash")

Set colItems = oSource.Items

For i = colItems.Count To 1 Step -1
Set oToMove = colItems(i)
Set oDummy = oToMove.Move(oTarget)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: We have no clue how it isnt working for you, try to add some relevent information about what is not working

Comment: I'd be happy to add more info.  What is it you are looking for?  I try and run the script above and, as far as I can see, nothing happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Perhaps I'm not stating my question clearly.  I'll try again.  I am trying to use a VB script that, when ran, moves (not copies) email from the Deleted Items folder in Outlook 2010 using an Exchange account to another folder.  So far, I have the script that you see above.  When I run the VB Script, as far as I can tell nothing happens.  No email is moved from the Deleted Items folder.  I'm hoping for assistance in the form that someone who knows VB Scripting can point out the error in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist you have a lot of stuff going on you dont need

Here is an example with comments that can be run as a macro within outlook.

```
Sub MoveDeletedItems()
'setup some error checking
On Error GoTo err_rpt
Dim oSource As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oTarget As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim oItem

'get the deleted Items folder
Set oSource = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems)
'get the folder under the Deleted Items folder called Trash
Set oTarget = oSource.Folders("Trash")
'loop through all the items in the source folder
For Each oMailItem In oSource.Items 
    'move the item to the target folder
    oItem.Move oTarget
Next

err_rpt:
If Err.Number > 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description
End If
'release the folders
Set oTarget = Nothing
Set oSource = Nothing
End Sub
```